# Typescript: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Type' and 'number' have no overlap

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I'm learning generics in Typescript and i have a function that first checks the argument passed in, does something, and returns the argument. If i try to check type of the argument there is no problem.

```
function identity<Type> (arg: Type): Type {
  if (typeof(arg) === 'number') console.log('test');
  return arg;
}
```

But if i try to compare to argument with a value like:

```
function identity<Type> (arg: Type): Type {
  if (arg === 5) console.log('test');
  return arg;
}
```

It throws an error saying:

```
generics.ts:2:6 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Type' and 'number' have no overlap.

2  if (arg === 5) console.log('test')
       ~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why it throws an error saying this condition will always return false. It can be true i think, i can pass an argument that is exactly the value i'm checking, and if i can't compare it with a value i think don't need to be able compare it with a type either.

Comment: What is "Type" ?

Comment: Cloud be posible that you have to check first if exist?  ``if(arg && arg === 5)``

Comment: `if (typeof arg === "number" && arg === 5)`

Comment: @jcalz Turns out your right, i use 4.5.4 and the problem originates from compiler. And it has been fixed in 4.8.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an incorrect TypeScript compiler behavior. It has been fixed in 4.8.4.

Error in 4.7.4: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQICYFMqLgTwB4AVfABywD5UAKAQwCcBzALlVIoEo2OtUBvUKnRhajJqgC801AFZOqGCgDOSADZYAdGqRMaAcjhZlcfQBpU4zgG4hw+w8dPnLgPSvUAPQD8dhljgIBjRxWxAAXyA)

Fixed in 4.8.4: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQICYFMqLgTwB4AVfABywD5UAKAQwCcBzALlVIoEo2OtUBvUKnRhajJqgC801AFZOqGCgDOSADZYAdGqRMaAcjhZlcfQBpU4zgG4hw+w8dPnLgPSvUAPQD8dhljgIBjRxWxAAXyA)

If you're not ready to upgrade, you can fix the issue by refining the type first:

```
function identity<Type> (arg: Type): Type {
  if (typeof(arg) === "number" && arg === 5) console.log('test', arg);
                                                              // ^? Type & number
  return arg;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQICYFMqLgTwB4AVfABywD5UAKAQwCcBzALlVIoEo2OtUBvUKnRhaBCkjD1mnVAF4FqAERQIAWwBGWBktQAyPakZN5igKyyYKAM5IANlgB0dpExoByOFmtx3AGiMZAG4hYTDwiMio6JjYqIB6eNQAPQB+UIYsOAgGNGMQkABfIA)

Comment: It would be interesting to find *where* this change happened in GitHub, but not so interesting that I would spend a lot of time on it myself.

Comment: @jcalz Likewise! I skimmed through the changelogs, and nothing stuck out to me as a change that would apply here.

Comment: Okay, it looks like changing it to `identity<Type extends unknown>` will fix it in TS4.7, and the issue is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48680 and was fixed at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48861